# Min Maxlength property not working in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I got an ion-input with type number and I have tried every possible way to set its minimum length as 6 but with no luck.I also have a decimal input field on which I want to validate that the numbers before the point should be of 3 numbers and after point should be of 2 numbers.Below is the code I tried.

```
<ion-label floating>Pin code</ion-label>
<ion-input type="number" name="pincode" [max]="maxPin" ngModel required>
</ion-input>
```

Comment: can you give some more clear explaination

Comment: I need that user should not be able to add pincode of more than 6 numbers.

Answer (score 2):

your html

```
    <form [formGroup]="myForm">

    <ion-item>
            <ion-label stacked>Pin Code</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number" maxlength="6" [(ngModel)]="pincode" formControlName="pincode">
            </ion-input>
    </ion-item>
<form>
```

Your ts file

```
import { FormBuilder,Validators } from '@angular/forms';


export class DemoForm{
myForm:any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public formBuilder: FormBuilder){
this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
          pincode: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6),  Validators.required])],

    })

}
```

Comment: what is myform?

Comment: this is not working please comment the complete code.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you still struggling with this issue. It seems that the maxLength is not working because of the element property type='number', if you would like to limit the length of characters use type='tel' instead. - Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

For PIN code input, we can use this method:

```
<ion-label floating>Pin code</ion-label>
<ion-input type="number" name="pincode" max="999999" min="100000" ngModel required>
</ion-input>
```

This will limit the input as minimum and maximum of 6 digits.
"maxlength" will not work with **number** type and then we use 'max' and 'min' to limit number input.

Answer (score -1):

We can set Minimum and maximum number manual.

```
<ion-input type="number" min="0" max="5"></ion-input>
```

Comment: PLease test before submitting answer